# Matlab and functions

Tags: matlab, function

I feel incredible stupid that I have to ask this question, but everyone was a noob once. Right?!?

For an assignment we have to implement the following sum:
PI - 3 = sum from i=1 to N of (-1)^(i+1) / i(i+1)(2i+1)  (shame about the lack of Mathjax here)
So in Java:

```
public static double[] computeSumOfPi(int N) { //returns the value of PI computed
                                               //with N terms of the sum and the 
                                               //last added term
    double term = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] result = new double[2];
    for(int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++) {
        term = Math.pow((-1),(i+1)) / i*(i+1)*(2*i+1);
        sum =  sum + term;
    }
    result[0] =  sum + 3;
    result[1] = term;
    return result;
}
```

In Matlab I tried the following

```
function [sumPi, lastTerm  ] = sumForPi( n )  %sumForPi.m
for i = 0 : n  
   term = (-1)^(i+1) / (i*(i + 1)*(2*i + 1));  
   temp = temp + term;   
end  
sumPi = temp + 3.0;  
lastTerm = term;  
end
```

Which I try to invoke:

> >> sumForPi(20)

Which returns the following error:

> undefined function or variable "temp"
>       Error in sumForPi (line 4)
>       temp = temp + term;

I would be delighted if someone could point out my (probably simple) mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not very clear whether the question is about Java or Matlab implementation. Also, the Java version may need parentheses around `i*(i+1)*(2*i+1)`, too.

Comment: @Gassa I added the Java implementation for making the sum more clear, but I understand the confusion. And you are right, I already spotted that error. (It was untested code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the initial value of `temp` before you read it. Hence, try to include `temp = 0;` before the loop, i,e.

```
function [sumPi, lastTerm  ] = sumForPi( n )  %sumForPi.m
temp = 0;
for i = 0 : n  
   term = (-1)^(i+1) / (i*(i + 1)*(2*i + 1));  
   temp = temp + term;   
end  
sumPi = temp + 3.0;  
lastTerm = term;  
end
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, thanks a lot and I'll refrain from asking stupid questions henceforth :p

Comment: @NigelOvermars Just curious, are you getting the desired values into sumPi? Because I am getting `-Inf` values in it.

Comment: The loop should start at i = 1, I had the same problem.